# Create a vector of accuracy measures in CARET for repeated hold-out samples

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret

I want to create a vector of accuracy measures from decision trees created by  repeating holdout samples (same size). I am trying this in CARET.

```
library(caret)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", 
                     repeats = 60, p=0.66)

mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, 
              method = "rpart", 
              trControl = ctrl)
```

My goal is now to get the vector of accuracy measures from each of the 60 repeated trials. But not sure what to do next.

With one trial, I would use the confusionMatrix(). But not sure what to do in this case.

Thoughts?

Comment: Specify a cost function for misclassification and apply it serially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for `method = "LGOCV"`, use `number = 60` not `repeats`.

There is a sub-object called `resamples`.

```
> ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", 
+                      number = 60, p=0.66)
> 
> mod1 <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, 
+               method = "rpart", 
+               trControl = ctrl)

> str(mod1$resample)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Accuracy: num  0.902 0.961 0.922 0.922 0.941 ...
 $ Kappa   : num  0.853 0.941 0.882 0.882 0.912 ...
 $ Resample: chr  "Resample14" "Resample13" "Resample15" "Resample11" ...
> length(unique(mod1$resample$Resample))
[1] 60
```

See the option `returnResamp` in `trainControl`. By default this saves the results for the optimal model. You can get them for each tuning parameter too.

Max